# Windows 7 64-bit can't find DVD drivers

Tags: windows-7, installation

When I start installing Windows 7 64-bit enterprise edition, after it asks for language and keyboard layout - it throws:

> [Can't find DVD drivers](http://en.kioskea.net/forum/affich-185843-Windows-7-install-cannot-find-DVD-driver)

What should I do in order to install it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Several solutions on this thread

http://social.answers.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/w7install/thread/48cdc51e-affc-40ec-a0ba-62d37948843c

Solutions include:

1. Load motherboard Chipset (sata) drivers at the start of setup
2. Install the OS from a flash drive
3. Download an ATAPI driver from Microsoft and load at start of setup
4. Be sure you have a good copy of the install disc.
5. When you get the error, do a hard shut down of the PC (power button), when it starts again immediately use F8 and disable driver signature enforcement, let set up continue.

http://taylorlife.com/archives/installing-windows-7-unsigned-dvd-driver/

> Since the Windows 7 installer removes itself if you exit it, we simply had to hard power off the laptop (instead of exiting the install), power it back on and let it boot from the hard disk, turned it back on, and then follow Solution 1 from the above link:  Boot, F8 to Advanced Boot Options, choose Disable Driver Signature Enforcement, and voila!  The installer continued into the install and had no more problems with the DVD drive.

Comment: Tried points 3-5 with no success.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if it's really a driver problem. Take a look at the *master/slave* jumpers on your HDD and DVD player (you can find the documentation on your material manufacturer's website), and verify that your motherboard has the same setup. Your HDD should be on *Master* and you DVD player on *Slave*.

A lot of OS installation problems come from the material setup.

Note : remember the original setup in case that doesn't solve anything.

Comment: Nah... didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

Used external DVD drive through USB.

That's not a solution, but acceptable workaround.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I was trying to install Win 7 x64 from a USB stick and I kept getting the CD/DVD driver error. I finally figured out the install was upset the USB stick was in one of my USB 3.0 ports. As soon as I moved the USB stick to a USB 2.0 port the install continued normally. Just a heads up.